# android: is it possible to keep a title above the spinner on actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have a spinner drop down menu and a drawermenu in the actionbar . I want to know if it is possible to have a title above the spinner which can be changed dynamically . Title is not part of spinner and do not depend on spinner item selected.  It is similar to Gmail where the spinner will select which account and the title i want to show which folder.

i am getting spinner by 
**

```
** spinnerAdapter = new AccountsSpinnerAdapter(
                getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_item,
                dataArray);

        /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = myfunction**
```

**

Comment: If you are using the `ActionBar` or `Toolbar` you can add custom views.

Answer (score 0):

No in this way you can not put on it. For doing this you should create a custom view and then inflate your view on there. create the custom layout and do the following

```
         DisplayMetrics mDisplayMatrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMatrics);
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
View mactionbar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main2, null);
```